# Taking a subset for a irregular sequence

Tags: r

I have a data matrix for my data which is 1990-2014, for 28 countries

I'm looking to make a subset of this matrix, taking an observation for each of the years 1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2014. This sequence is irregular and so i keep on getting observations for years outside this observation period. Is there a way to make a subset meeting these criteria? Thanks

My dataset looks like

[the data matrix i'm looking at is y, it is enclosed within a panel dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPSVo.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this is to make a vector of the years you're looking for and use the `%in%` keyword to filter rows. This should work.

```
interesting_years <- c(1990,1995,2000,2005,2010,2014)
interesting_data <- Growth[Growth$year %in% interesting_years, ]
```

Comment: I like your name for the variable, I'll give this a shot tomorrow morning, thank you